# I cannot get the correct answer as same as what the solution doc. provided about Tableau business question

Tags: tableau-api

Question:

```
 Answer using the “Insurance Data” worksheet from the Car Insurance excel file.
For cars insured in New York state, find the top 10 to makes of car with the highest average
annual premium. Of these 10, which had the most policies associated with it?
a. Ford
b. Toyota
c. Chrysler
d. Chevrolet
e. Ford
```

Even though I used 'Add to context', I cannot get the same view/result as the solution provided. Please help me out. Thank you so much and I appreciate.

Here is the data download link
[data downlaod link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-bOTvEkCD_9hzGc9xqYjeoMdbmtHfus3/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's Chevrolet

[image]

The make filter is:

[image]

Fingers crossed that matches the solution doc!

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution is very good. The solution the doc provided does not mention to filter [make], this is why I always got the different result as doc shows. Now, I got the same result. Thank you so much.